# How do I limit document upload access to an IP while allowing search for a Principal in AWS Cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

Is there any way you can limit document upload access to an IP while allowing search for a Principal in AWS Cloudsearch? All the policies examples seem to allow either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid": "search_only",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["cloudsearch:search"],
      "Principal": {"AWS":["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"]}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "upload_only",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": ["cloudsearch:document"],
      "Condition": {"IpAddress":{"aws:SourceIp":"192.0.2.0/32"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

This is based off of the examples at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-access.html#policy-examples